# Find $A(x)=a+b\cos(cx+d)$

Tags: calculus, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

Consider the function $A(x)$ of the form $a+b\cos(cx+d)$.We want to determine the coefficients so that the function have the following properties:

1.$A:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ be a continuous increasing function such that $A(0)=0\ and \ A(1)=1$.

2.There exist a continuous function $U:\mathbb R\rightarrow [0,1]$ with compactly support subject to

$U(x) =
\begin{cases}
0  & \text{if $x\lt x_0$ } \\
A(\frac {x-x_0}{x_1-x_0}), & \text{if $x_0\le x \lt x_1$ }\\
1& \text{if $x=x_1$}\\
A(\frac {x_2-x}{x_2-x_1}), & \text{if $x_1\le x \lt x_2$ }\\
0  & \text{if $x\ge x_2$ }
\end{cases}
$.

Comment: Is there any condition on $U(x)$? Is it required to be continuous, or something? Is this problem from some particular contest?

Comment: yes....u(x) is continuous and compactly supported....

Comment: Please edit this, and anything else you have left out, into the body of the question. People shouldn't have to read the comments to understand the question.

Comment: Isn't a half of sinusoid enough...?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you can define
$A(x)$ with
$$\begin{align}
a &= \frac {-\cos p}{\cos r - \cos p} \\
b &= \frac 1{\cos r - \cos p} \\
c &= r-p \\
d &= p
\end{align}$$
for any $p,\ r$ such that $\pi\le p\lt r\le 2\pi$.

The simplest case is, of course,
$$A(x)=\frac{1+\cos(\pi(x+1))}2$$
with $a = b = 1/2,\ c = d = \pi$, obtained for $p=\pi,\ r=2\pi$.